# In beamer, how do you make \only work after the frame?

Tags: beamer, overlays

I believe I understand `\only<...>{...}` fairly well, but I'm having problems with it. In particular, if `\only` comes after the frame it's supposed to be on, the text doesn't appear.

Here is a very simple example:

```
\begin{frame}
\pause 
text 
\pause 
more text
\pause 
even more text
\only<1>{only text}
\end{frame}
```

The "only text" never shows up. But if I put the `\only<1>{only text}` earlier (before the very first pause), then it appears.

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: By the way, here's what I'm actually trying to get to work.  The images at the bottom don't appear.

```
\begin{frame}
\pause
%
\begin{lemma}\label{lemma1}
\pause 
Fix $\eta:[0,+\infty]\to[0,+\infty]$ for which there exists 
\pause $\xi:[0,+\infty]\to[0,+\infty]$ which is convex, pointwise 
dominates $\eta$, is finite on $[0,+\infty)$ and vanishes at the origin.
\pause Given $c\in[0,+\infty)$ arbitrary, define $\eta_c:[0,+\infty]\to[0,+\infty]$ by
\pause
%
$$\eta_c(x):=\max\Big\{cx,\inf_{\substack{\mbox{\tiny$\xi$ convex on $[0,+\infty]$}\\
{\mbox{\tiny$\xi\geq\eta$ on $[0,+\infty]$}}}}\xi(x)\Big\},\qquad\forall\,x\in[0,+\infty].$$
%
\pause Then $c\,{\rm id}\leq\eta_c$ on $[0,+\infty]$, 
\pause $\eta\leq\eta_c$ on $[0,+\infty]$, 
\pause $\eta_c$ is convex, 
\pause $\eta_c^{-1}(\{0\})=\{0\}$, 
\pause $\eta_c^{-1}(\{+\infty\})=\{+\infty\}$, 
\pause is strictly increasing 
\pause and continuous.
\end{lemma}
%
\begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{\textheight}
\only<1>{\begin{figure}\includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{Eta01}\end{figure}}
\only<2>{\begin{figure}\includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{Eta02}\end{figure}}
\only<3>{\begin{figure}\includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{Eta03}\end{figure}}
\only<4>{\begin{figure}\includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{Eta04}\end{figure}}
\only<5>{\begin{figure}\includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{Eta05}\end{figure}}
\only<6>{\begin{figure}\includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{Eta06}\end{figure}}
\end{overlayarea}
%
\end{frame}
```

Comment: From the `beamer` doc: *If you say `\pause` somewhere in a frame, only the text on the frame up to the `\pause` command is shown on the first slide.*.

Comment: Now that's good to know. Is there a command other than \pause I can use? Or is there some way to put text higher up appear beneath text lower? I tried \vskip but, of course, that pushes everything down.

Comment: @danzibr: I would use `\onslide<1->{text} \onslide<2->{more text} \onslide<3->{even more text} \onslide<1>{only text}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the pause coounter right so that the `only` specification is read before the first `\pause`. Like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\pause
text

\pause
more text

\pause
even more text

\pause[0]
\only<1>{only text}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This will produce:
[image]

Changing the pause counter values (the number inside brackets) you can rearrange the order of appearance of the items. For example you can let the `\only` content to appear alongside the first chunk of text, etc.

I could not compile your longer example (missing `overlayarea` arguments?) but the rationale is the same.

Comment: Right, missing overlayarea arguments.

And thank you! That knowledge will allow me to do it. Truly appreciated.